# String objects with various Hyperlinks in Textview?

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I have a String objects that contain hyperlinks which I'm trying to make clickable in a Textview, here's an example:

```
    String descrption = "\"Cardano is a decentralised platform" +
            " that will allow complex programmable transfers of" +
            " value in a secure and scalable fashion. It is one" +
            " of the first blockchains to be built in the highly" +
            " secure Haskell programming language. Cardano is developing" +
            " a <a href=\\\"https://www.coingecko.com/en?category_id=29\\\">smart contract platform</a>" +
            " which seeks to deliver more advanced features than any protocol previously developed." +
            " It is the first blockchain platform to evolve out of a scientific philosophy and a research-first driven approach." +
            " The development team consists of a large global collective of expert engineers and researchers.\\r\\n\\r\\n" +
            "The Cardano project is different from other blockchain projects as it openly addresses the need for regulatory oversight whilst maintaining" +
            " consumer privacy and protections through an innovative software architecture.";


    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.description_textview);
    Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

But this is how it comes out:

[image]

How can I get the hyperlinks to format correctly?

Comment: Take a look at [HtmlCompat.fromHtml()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/HtmlCompat#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Comment: That works, but it removes all newlines and carriage returns, so I'm only getting one long continuous text.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working with the following code:

```
descrption= descrption.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "<p>");
Spanned spanned= Html.fromHtml(descrption);
textView .setText(spanned);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: `<br>` would be a better choice than `<p>` for line breaks.